# Get all the list of roles from sql in spring boot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a table like - (roleid, rolename)

User will give list of rolenames and I want to find all the matched records. If any of the rolename not exist in database should through an error in database.

Do i need iterate all the rolenames list and every time call findbyName() ? or any simple way ?

Comment: Probably have a loop that goes over each rolename and returns entry by rolename. Combined with a custom exception for a case when the entry returned == null

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a database call in a for loop is an expensive operation. Instead, it's better to load the data at once and do logic operation on it.

`findByNameIn(List<String> roleNames)` should do the trick for your case. Loading the data and checking the size of returned list with user given list or extracting matching names seems to be a better solution.